# JS how can in replace a string data for a given one Ex: id:"32" and id:"12" for id:"44" in the same function

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

in my project the user can inter a google maps iframe in a textbox and the the iframe will be displayed in a div, the problem is that usually the iframe come with its own width and height values and is bigger than the container.

Im trying to solve this replacing the width and height value, by default the width of a google maps iframe is 600 so i used replace ('"width="600"', '"width=300"') but what if the inserted text has a different value than 600? how could i replace it?.

also how can i do the same for the height in the same function.

this is my code

```js
function Process(){
  var map1 = document.getElementById("iframe1").value;
     var obj = document.getElementById("map1");
  var res = map1.replace('width="600"', 'width="300"');
       {
          obj.innerHTML = res;
      alert(res)
        }
      }
```

```css
/*
You can use this iframe

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m17!1m8!1m3!1d14376.793148942863!2d-100.2753853!3d25.7309555!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m6!3e6!4m0!4m3!3m2!1d25.7312454!2d-100.2732824!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2smx!4v1445727202935" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>*/
.div {
  width:300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.map1 iframe {
  width:300px;
  height: 200px;
  
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title> test</title>
  
</head>

<body>
  
  <input type="text" id="iframe1" value="enter iframe here">
  
  <div class="container">
  <div id="map1"> </div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="button" value="go!" onclick="Process()" />
</body>
```

im doing this because the container is 300x200 but if a iframe with it´s own values is inserted the map will be bigger than the container.

do you have any ideas?
is there a easier ways to do this?

UPDATE:

Found the answer 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_width2

Comment: you seem to be wanting to change `style` not `innerHTML` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: please, provide an example of expected `document.getElementById("iframe1").value`

Comment: ex: <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=5" width="650" height="490" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Comment: i want indeed change the style but the style is directly received from a textbox with its own values and pasted directly to the code. so i cant manipulated it from the css as you can see in the example